# Obtener la id de una fila en la que hay una coincidencia de un campo

Tags: php, mysql, php5

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
$check = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE validationCode = ?');
$check->bind_param("s",$code); //La variable code contiene un codigo de validación
$check->execute();
$check->store_result();

/* Aquí lo que pretendo es obtener la id de la fila en la que existe esa coincidencia */

$check->close();
```

El código no presenta errores. Cuando pruebo con **`$rows = $check->num_rows;`**, **sí, me devuelve un valor mayor que 0**, pero lo que no consigo hacer es obtener la **`id` de esa fila**.

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿el objetivo de querer obtener la id es para usarla para otra cosa o se trata sólo de verificar si hay registros? Si es sólo verificar que hay registros no tienes por qué recoger la id. Otra cosa: Si sólo necesitas la id, usa un `SELECT id FROM... ` para que tu código esté optimizado.

Comment: @A.Cedano no solo pretendo comprobar si hay registros, pretendo comprobar si existe ese registro (solo puede haber una coincidencia) y además sacar la id de la fila de esa coincidencia y posteriormente cambiar unos datos en esa fila.

Comment: Entonces con la respuesta de Marcos debería funcionar, aunque , te repito, si solo necesitas el id no tienes por qué hacer un SELECT * ... seleccionando campos que no vas a utilizar. Yo, por este y más motivos prefiero usar PDO, el cual tiene métodos como fetchcolumn para obtener una columna en específico sin complicaciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que estoy haciendo es simplemente un boceto del proyecto en MySQL, el usar PDO es lo de menos ahora, de todos modos en su momento usé `get_result()` y me daba error, pero tendré que revisarlo.

Comment: No es _tan de menos_ como crees. El uso de PDO te ahorrará muchísimo tiempo en cosas sencillas como estas o en cosas que podrían ser más complicadas. Eso sí, tienes que tenerlo bien configurado. Otro de los problemas de MySQLi es que para usar get_result() tienes que tener instalado el driver mysqlnd es quizá por eso el error. Como decía, MySQLi tiene una serie de complicaciones y limitaciones a la hora de usarlo y de manejar los datos que a mi particularmente no me gusta. Resulta que no siempre se llega más rápido por el hecho de tomar el camino más corto. Eso suele pasar mucho con MySQLi.

Comment: @A.Cedano no niego nada de lo que dices, estoy de acuerdo, pero me refiero que lo que estoy haciendo es una simple prueba, con 2 tonterías, cuando haga una base de datos de verdad usaré PDO, de todos modos lo de mysqlnd lo sabía pero no quise instalarlo precisamente por lo que dices, básicamente que usaré PDO en vez de MySQLi

Comment: Es que sin ese driver instalado el obtener el valor de una columna se hace algo complicado con MySQLi comparado con PDO. Recuerdo haber hecho una respuesta  con una función que emulaba el FETCH ASSOC usando MSQLi pero no la tengo ahora a mano. De todos modos te dejo esta clase PDO por si te interesa: https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO  Fíjate en la explicación lo fácil que se hace obtener el valor de una columna.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya implementé por completo PDO en mi proyecto, gracias por tus consejos!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Así por ejemplo:

```
$check = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE validationCode = ?');
$check->bind_param("s",$code); //La variable code contiene un codigo de validación
$check->execute();

$result = $check->get_result();
while ($user = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  var_dump($user);
}

$check->close();
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Marcos, esta tarde probaré tu respuesta :)

Comment: al final terminé usando PDO ya que me ahorraba mucho trabajo, pero no quiere decir que tu respuesta no haya funcionado, tu respuesta funciona perfectamente usando mysqlnd.

Comment: Disculpas por haber tardado tanto en responder, pero para futuros usuarios que vean la pregunta les recomendaría usar *PDO*.